# How to dynamically call subjects from service?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Having a service with the following subjects

```
  subjectOne$ = new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
  subjectTwo$ = new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
  subjectThree$ = new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
  subjectFour$ = new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
```

How can I call them dynamically from the component?

```
onToggle(number: string) {
    this.myService.subjectOne$.next(this.selected[number]);
  }
```

I can do the param inside next() but how do I call subjectXXXX$ dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to manage subjects inside map and access them dynamically

```
subjectMaps: {[key: string]: Subject<Partial<boolean>>} = {
    one : new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
    two : new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
    three: new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
    four : new Subject<Partial<boolean>>();
  }
```

to facilitate access you define a function in the service that returns the

```
subjectByKey(subjectKey: string): Subject<Partial<boolean>> {
    return this.subjectMaps[subjectKey];
  }
```

and call from your component

```
onToggle(number: string) {
    this.myService.subjectByKey('one').next(this.selected[number]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but I think we can use an object for the subjects

```
subjects = {
  1: new Subject<Partial<boolean>>(),
  2: new Subject<Partial<boolean>>(),
  ....
}

onToggle(number: string) {
    this.myService.subjects[number].next(/* whatever value */);
  }
```